# Errors were encountered while processing: cinnamon nemo nemo-fileroller

Tags: installation, apt

I am getting  the following error

> > Errors were encountered while processing:
> >     cinnamon
> >     nemo
> >     nemo-fileroller

When I run `sudo apt-get install <anything>`. I have tried `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get -f autoremove`. I get the same error. I am unable to install anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Synaptic Package Manager to remove those bad installs. Seems like apt-get cant do all that Synaptic can do.

Comment: Can you give more details on how to do it. The answer is very unclear.